# Does anyone know a Vtunnel bookmarklet?

Tags: webapp-rec

You may know [vtunnel.com](http://www.vtunnel.com). You can access blocked sites through this. There is a form which takes the URL of the site I want to go to and, after posting, the site appears with some Vtunnel URLs, unblocked.

I was thinking of a bookmarklet which will take the current URL typed in the address box and post it to Vtunnel with the appropriate form values and the site will appear.

Is there any such bookmarklet?

And if one is not there, I think it will not be difficult to make. But I am not a JavaScript guy.

Or, is it not even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this bookmarklet below:

```
javascript:_vtunnel_form=document.createElement('FORM');_vtunnel_form.name='login';_vtunnel_form.method='POST';_vtunnel_form.action='http://www.vtunnel.com/index.php/1010110A/ee908e12b7cb248c8f';_vtunnel_h1=document.createElement('INPUT');_vtunnel_h1.type='TEXT';_vtunnel_h1.name='username';_vtunnel_h1.value=location.href;_vtunnel_form.appendChild(_vtunnel_h1);_vtunnel_h2=document.createElement('INPUT');_vtunnel_h2.type='HIDDEN';_vtunnel_h2.name='r4';_vtunnel_h2.value=' checked';_vtunnel_form.appendChild(_vtunnel_h2);_vtunnel_h3=document.createElement('INPUT');_vtunnel_h3.type='HIDDEN';_vtunnel_h3.name='fa';_vtunnel_form.appendChild(_vtunnel_h3);_vtunnel_h4=document.createElement('INPUT');_vtunnel_h4.type='HIDDEN';_vtunnel_h4.name='if';_vtunnel_h4.value=' checked';_vtunnel_form.appendChild(_vtunnel_h4);document.body.appendChild(_vtunnel_form);_vtunnel_form.submit();
```

> See [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) questions:
>
> [Problem while creating “copy-paste JavaScript”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3991779/395703)
>   &
>   [How to create a form dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3991204/395703)